# Не получается подключить Tomcat 9 на ubuntu

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Не могу запустить tomcat из папки opt/.

Когда указываю в конфигурациях intellij idea(Tomcat Home) каталог (/opt/tomcat/). Пишет - The selected is not a valid Tomcat home. Как все-таки запустить Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

у Linux своя особенная система каталогов и прав доступа к ним (не как в windows, когда пользователь имеет доступ ко всему содержимому любой папки). Такой каталог, как opt требует дополнительной конфигурации для обращающихся к нему. Что для обычной работы с Tomcat из под IntellijIdea не всегда удобно и нужно.

Поэтому, рекомендую просто поместить Tomcat в удобный каталог, рядом с обычными документами (Java проектами) и спокойно запускать его там (в том числе менять конфигурацию, деплоить в него, и т.д.) без sudo и прочих настроек...

Comment: Я это пробовал сделать, но все равно та же ошибка, получилось только когда эту команду написал - chmod -R 755 foldername.